# How to use a variable as a socket name with io.to(<socket name>).emit

Tags: javascript, node.js, socket.io

I am trying to add a function to a socket.io server which allows users to direct message other users.

I am able to get the target user's socket id and send it to the server, and I'm trying to use `io.to(recipient).emit("dm", {description: message});` to send the message to the target. the issue I'm running into is that I can't seem to replace 'recipient' with a variable. when I try to,  there is nothing sent to the client. The socket.io docs aren't great on this, I find no mention of being able to use a variable in an io.to function. does anyone have any information?

Comment: What do you mean with "use a variable"? Isn't `recipient` a variable?

Comment: @Aioros sorry for not describing that correctly, what I mean is the target socket id is stored in `recipient`, but `io.to(recipient).emit("dm", {description: message});` doesn't work, I think because it isn't reading the data stored in `recipient`.

Comment: That should work in theory. Do you get any error message? Could we see your code with a little more context?

Comment: @Aioros I think the server tries to send the message, but nothing happens on the client side.

Comment: Can you show the client code?

Comment: following - having exactly the same problem here too. Should be a 'socket.id' value as 'recipient'